# OSI 7 layers to TCP/IP 4 Layers

Tags: networking, layer

my question is very simple ;

why was the 7 layers in OSI reduced to 4 layers in TCP/IP ?

i have tried searching google but came emptyhanded

Comment: I think you confuse TPS with TCP. So you should find lots of information when you search for TCP/IP in comparison to OSI layers.

Comment: They are simply network stack models. There are a multitude of such models. Remember that they are just models, and nothing strictly follow them in the real world.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer the below link

https://www.ischool.utexas.edu/~wyllys/ITIPMaterials/NotesOnInterconnection.html

Summary :

In essence, we can say that there are two different, but related models, for the interconnection of computer networks. The first is the OSI/ISO networking model; this approach originated in Europe and Europe's political model of the state-owned and -operated Post, Telephone, and Telegraph (PTT). It has seven layers and is the result of international deliberation that formulated the model before there were protocols to support it. This approach, not unintentionally, favored incumbent businesses with large market share, emphasized existing proprietary software protocols (especially IBM products), and relied on telephony and national PTTs for its conceptual foundation. The OSI/ISO model so emphasized telephony that it hardly mentioned computing. Such standards fiats also tend to stifle innovation.

In contrast to this top-down approach is what some have termed the TCP approach; this approach grew mostly in America and is deeply influenced by military concerns. In this case, the protocols preceded the model and sprang from what networking researchers and users were actually doing. The weakness of such a bottom-up, "empirical" approach is that it engenders great uncertainty about directions of research, interoperability, investment options, governmental and private roles, and the like. Further, the TCP approach does little to distinguish the concepts of protocol, interface, and service. These weaknesses are partially based on the ARPANET assumptions that network users are technical experts with great programming sophistication.

So we might summarize by saying that the OSI model has been very useful for talking about computer networks because of its emphasis on layering; but its protocols are very weak. On the other hand, the TCP protocols are resounding successes, but the TCP conceptual model is weak.